# Passing props between screens using React Navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app where I'm using React Navigation to navigate between screens. I have a Drawer component that contains a "Give me a Random Recipe!!" button. When the button is pressed, I want to navigate to the RecipeScreen and pass a random recipe object as well as its corresponding category and title.

However, I'm facing an issue where the category prop in the RecipeScreen is always undefined, even though I'm passing it correctly from the DrawerContainer. I have checked the logs, and the category is correctly logged in the DrawerContainer component before navigation.

I have simplified the relevant code snippets for both components below:

Drawer.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { getCategoryById } from "../../data/API";

const Drawer = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch random recipe here if needed
  }, []);

  const handleNavigate = () => {
    const randomRecipe = {}; // Replace with the random recipe object
    const category = getCategoryById(randomRecipe.categoryID);
    const title = category ? category.name : "";

    navigation.navigate("Recipe", { item: randomRecipe, category, title });

    navigation.closeDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <MenuButton
        title="Give me a Random Recipe!!"
        onPress={handleNavigate}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

DrawerContainer.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    closeDrawer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }),
};

export default DrawerContainer;
```

RecipeScreen.js:

```
export default function RecipeScreen(props) {
  const { navigation, route } = props;

  const category = route.params.category;

  const title = item.title;

  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
  const [recipeData, setRecipeData] = useState(null);

  const slider1Ref = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerLeft: () => (
        <BackButton
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
          }}
        />
      ),
      headerRight: () => <View />,
    });
  }, []);

  const renderImage = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item }} />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://10.11.55.7:111/rest', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const matchedRecipe = data.find(recipe => recipe.recipeID === item.recipeId);
        if (matchedRecipe) {
          console.log(matchedRecipe.recipeID);
          setRecipeData(matchedRecipe);
        } else {
          console.log('No matching recipe found');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Fetch error:', error);
        // Handle the error here
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.carouselContainer}>
        <View style={styles.carousel}>
          <Carousel
            ref={slider1Ref}
            data={item.photosArray}
            renderItem={renderImage}
            sliderWidth={viewportWidth}
            itemWidth={viewportWidth}
            inactiveSlideScale={1}
            inactiveSlideOpacity={1}
            firstItem={0}
            loop={false}
            autoplay={false}
            autoplayDelay={500}
            autoplayInterval={3000}
            onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(0)}
          />
          <Pagination
            dotsLength={item.photosArray.length}
            activeDotIndex={activeSlide}
            containerStyle={styles.paginationContainer}
            dotColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92)"
            dotStyle={styles.paginationDot}
            inactiveDotColor="white"
            inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
            inactiveDotScale={0.6}
            carouselRef={slider1Ref.current}
            tappableDots={!!slider1Ref.current}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.infoRecipeContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.infoRecipeName}>{item.title}</Text>
        <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
          {category && (
            <Text style={styles.category}>
              {getCategoryName(item.categoryId).toUpperCase()}
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

I get an error on this line when switching screens:

```
{getCategoryName(item.categoryId).toUpperCase()}
```

because

```
const category = route.params.category;
```

is undefined when I switch from the drawer screen to the recipe screen.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to correctly pass the category prop from Drawer to RecipeScreen. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the randomRecipe, category and title in the name of item from Drawer.js correctly, But, You have to change the props to access the prop in your RecipeScreen.js like this ,

```js
export default function RecipeScreen(props) {

  const { navigation, route } = props;

  const { category } = route.params.item; // Destructure the category from item

  const title = route.params.title; 

}
```

Comment: `const { category } = route.params.item;` 
 this doesn't destructure the category from item. it prints undefined(when I do console.log(category). and console.log(route.params.item) prints out the recipe data. Before navigating to recipescreen the category has the correct value

Comment: I just realized , that when if we dont navigate to recipescreen from drawer.js category has the value undefined. After navigating it is also undefined. Can we change the value of category once it has the value undefined ?

Comment: @konoha . After reviewing further . Change these couple of lines in your code ,
Declaring statement --> 'const category = route.params?.category;'  & 
Binding Line --> ' {getCategoryName(category.categoryId).toUpperCase()}' Inside the infoContainer.. try using this